# I would like to know in CSS backdrop-filter mean Gaussian blur?

Tags: css, c, blur, gaussian

I would like to know in CSS backdrop-filter mean Gaussian blur?

How to use C to implement the "background-filter: blur(60px)" feature in CSS?

Are there any useful third-party libraries?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions, and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please note that asking for library recommendations is not on-topic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So it is not likely that you will be using C to directly use CSS as that is a web styling language, but if you do a bit of research here or online, you will find that there are main papers and ways to approach this visual feature. It is a very complex realm as there are many ways to optimize it and implement it. You also have to consider if you are using an existing C UI library or if you are making custom GUI. Either way, you may have to do a lot of implementation yourself.